# In which call Sonos is showing the custom error messages?

Tags: sonos

It would be nice to know in the `CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES` section of the [Error handling](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/460) guide which calls actually work with custom error messages and shows it. As an example, as of right now, returning a `soapFault` in the `getMediaMetadata` shows `An error occurred while adding songs to the Queue (701)` instead of showing the custom error message.

I tested those calls with the desktop Sonos app for Mac and the Android app.

Showing it: `getMediaURI`, `getMetadata`, `getDeviceAuthToken`

Not showing it: `getMediaMetadata`, `getAppLink`

Can `getMediaMetadata` work with custom error messages too?